# integrate Chartkick with a rails 5.2 api only app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, rails-api, ruby-on-rails-5.2, chartkick

When integrating the `chartkick` gem in my rails api-only app, the documentation states that the js needs to be improted like this in the `application.js`file.  The app being an api-only app doesn't have an `application.js` file.

```
//= require Chart.bundle
//= require chartkick
```

How do I require chartkick for use with `activeadmin` without an `application.js` file?

Comment: Did you find solution for tthis?

Answer (score 1):

The quick solution is trying to do a monkey patch for this file `app/assets/javascripts/active_admin/base.es6` and add your Chartkick stuff.

Comment: Which folder did you put chartkick js file in?

Comment: just did bundle install after adding the gem